# Open .webm files with VLC automatically on Safari

Tags: safari, video, file, vlc

Currently on Safari I can copy the address of a .webm video file and play it in VLC by opening it with the "Open Network" option. If I open a .webm file on a page alone it defaults to downloading the file. How can I make it so that opening a .webm file opens VLC and loads the file from that URL?

Here is an example of a link to a .webm file that I would like to automatically open with VLC: https://i.4cdn.org/g/1584979729118.webm

Comment: Did you try to install VLC Plugin first for Safari and test it? https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/40b3y3/this_is_how_you_can_play_webm_in_safari/ , M not sure if this work or not as I haven't tested it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to be installed on up-to-date versions of Safari.